# Deprecated pd.rolling_corr() into Pandas 19

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How would the below line of Python 3 code be updated to adjust for the depreciated 'pd.rollingcorr()' in pandas?

```
FutureWarning: pd.rolling_corr is deprecated for Series and will be removed in a future version, replace with

#Series.rolling(window=12).corr(other=<Series>)


TX_AK_12corr = pd.rolling_corr(HPI_data['TX'], HPI_data['AK'], 12)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
HPI_data['TX'].rolling(12).corr(HPI_data['AK'])
```

where TX is the first and AK is the second Series. 12 is the window. As cor(X, Y) = cor(Y, X), the order is not important.

```
corr1 = ser.rolling(12).corr(ser2)
corr2 = ser2.rolling(12).corr(ser)
corr1.equals(corr2)
Out: True
```

Comment: And to confirm, would the other not matter? That is, would 
    HPI_data['AK'].rolling(12).corr(HPI_data['TX'])

work as well?

Comment: Yes, the order is not important. I've updated the post.